# Count even,odd and perfect number for arrays java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

**Question**: 
    Write a Number class that can be used to determine if a number is odd, even, or
perfect. Then, use this Number class to determine how many numbers in the list are odd, even, and perfect.

**Number Class**:

```
public class Number
{
  private Integer number;
  public Number(int n)
  {
    number=n;
  }
  public boolean isEven() 
  {
    if(number % 2 == 0)
      return true;
    else 
      return false; 
  }
  public boolean isOdd()
  {
    if(number % 2 != 0)
      return true;
    else 
      return false;  
  }
  public boolean isPerfect()
  {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<number; i++)
    {
       if(number % i == 0)
          count += i;
    }
    if(number == count)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
       return false;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return "" +number;
  }
}
```

My number class is running good there is no problem in my Number class. But in my number analyzer class where i find the number of odd,even and perfect.

**Number Analyzer class:**

```
public class NumberAnalyzer
{
  private ArrayList<Number> list;
  public NumberAnalyzer(int l)
  {
    list=l;
  }
  public int countOdds()
  {
    int odd = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
      if(list.isOdd() == true)
        return odd++;
    }    
  }
  public int countEvens()
  {
    int even = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x<list.size(); x++)
    {
      if(list.isEven() == true)
        return even++;
    }
  } 
  public int countPerfects()
  {
    int perfect = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z<list.size(); z++)
    {
       if(list.isPerfect() == true)
         return perfect++;
    }
  }

  public String toString()
  {
     return "" + list;
  }

}
```

Please make correction on this class so my program run perfectly. I do not understand the problem please make change in this so program work perfectly.
**Runner of program:**

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Runner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        int[] r = {5, 12, 9, 6, 1, 4, 8, 6 };
        NumberAnalyzer test = new NumberAnalyzer(r);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("odd count = "+test.countOdds());
        out.println("even count = "+test.countEvens());
        out.println("perfect count = "+test.countPerfects()+"\n\n\n");


    }
}
```

**Correct answers with this Runner:**

```
[5, 12, 9, 6, 1, 4, 8, 6]
odd count = 3
even count = 5
perfect count = 2
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Your program is not working as expected because in your `countOdds()`, `countEvens()` and `countPerfects()` the `return` statement in the `for` loop will automatically exit the for if the condition is met, and the result will be either 0 or 1. You have to remove the `return` statement from `for` loop and place it outside.

Comment: And `if ( condition == true )` can be simplified to `if (condition)`

Comment: Should not list.isOdd() be list[i].isOdd()? Same below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand how it could work if it even didn't complile but nevermind. You need to change 2 classes: NumberAnalyzer and Runner. Please have a look:

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Number[] r = {new Number(5), new Number(12), new Number(9), new Number(6),
                new Number(1), new Number(4), new Number(8), new Number(6)};
        NumberAnalyzer test = new NumberAnalyzer(r);
        out.println(test);
        out.println("odd count = " + test.countOdds());
        out.println("even count = " + test.countEvens());
        out.println("perfect count = " + test.countPerfects() + "\n\n\n");


    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class NumberAnalyzer {
    private List<Number> list;

    public NumberAnalyzer(Number[] l) {
        list = Arrays.asList(l);
    }

    public int countOdds() {
        int odd = 0;
        for (Number value : list) {
            if (value.isOdd() == true) {
                odd++;
            }
        }
        return odd;
    }

    public int countEvens() {
        int even = 0;
        for (Number value : list) {
            if (value.isEven() == true) {
                even++;
            }
        }
        return even;
    }

    public int countPerfects() {
        int perfect = 0;
        for (Number value : list) {
            if (value.isPerfect() == true) {
                perfect++;
            }
        }
        return perfect;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + list;
    }

}
```

in that case it returns a correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach for resolving this problem has a lot of problems, especially in `NumberAnalyzer` class.

1) You should call the `isOdd()`, `isEven()` etc. on an element of the list, not on the list itself -> `list.get(i).isEven()`

2) The `return even++` will exit the loop and return 1 if the condition is met, and the method is not even working since you don't have a return statement in case if the `if` statement from the `for` loop doesn't get executed.

3) Not a big problem, but the `x` and `z` can be declared as `i` too -> more intuitive ( **i** ndex)

4) The `isPerfect()` method is not correct, an easy solution to solve this problem could be using `Math.sqrt()` and `Math.floor()`

5) You're trying to pass an `int[]` array and the constructor expect an `int`. And after this, you have an `ArrayList<Number>` inside the `NumberAnalyzer` class and you're trying to assign to this list an `int` value.

Solutions:

1) + 2) + 3) :

```
public class NumberAnalyzer {
private List<Number> list; //Changed the ArrayList<> to List<> 

public NumberAnalyzer(List<Number> l) {
    list = l;
}

public int countOdds() {
    int odd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).isOdd())
            odd++;
    }
    return odd;
} // SAME FOR THE OTHER METHODS.
}
```

4)

```
public boolean isPerfect()
{
  int square = Math.sqrt(number);
  return (square - Math.floor(square)) == 0;
}
```

5) The static void main method should now look like this:

```
        Integer[] r = {5, 12, 9, 6, 1, 4, 8, 6};
        List<Integer> rList = Arrays.asList(r);
        List<Number> numberList = rList.stream().map(Number::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        NumberAnalyzer test = new NumberAnalyzer(numberList);
```